# Finding Multiple file type with date restriction linux

Tags: linux, sas, sas-dis

I use SAS Grid and I'm trying to set up a process which looks for files older than 180 days. I need to locate both .sas7bdat and .sas7bndx files. The results are output to a .txt file for manipulation in SASDI

I have been able to locate each file type separately but when I try for multiple extensions I get the error;4

> find: paths must precede expression: (-iname

The code I am using is;

```
$find /opt/SAS/SASdata/DOM/Prod/5_userdata/  -type f \(-iname "*.sas7bdat" -o -iname "*.sas7bndx" \) -mtime +180 -ls >mofindx.txt
```

I have tried a few variations of the above like removing the \, or ( or changing the position of the query and get variations on the error.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/how-to-use-find-command-to-search-for-multiple-extensions

Comment: Try `find /opt/SAS/SASdata/DOM/Prod/5_userdata/  -type f \(-iname "*.sas7bdat" -o "*.sas7bndx" \) -mtime +180 -ls >mofindx.txt `

Comment: Note: Don't use `-iname`, use regular `-name`.  SAS will only recognize datasets where the physical filename is in lowercase on Unix systems.

Comment: following the link from Digvijay i found
find ./ -type f \( -iname \*.sas7bdat -o  -iname \*.sas7bndx \) -mtime +180 -ls >mofindx.txt

which works in shell but will not pass from DIS - i need to get it to do this for automation